# Number Theory prove gcd[(gcd(x,y),y)] = gcd(x,y)

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

$$gcd[(gcd(x,y),y)] = gcd(x,y)$$

Intuitively, I realize that GCD has these same properties, but I assume that this is not enough. normally showing that one operation is the same as another, we must prove that these functions have the same price in all possible sets of arguments. Please show me a way to prove these facts formally.

And how can I prove ab|cd if a|c,b|c and gcd(a,b)=d?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put $d = \gcd (x,y)$. Then $\gcd (d,y)\leq d$. Since $d$ is a common divisor of $y$ and itself, we conclude $d = \gcd(d,y)$.

Comment: Thanks! How can I prove ab|cd if $a|c , b|c $ and $gcd(a,b)=d$?

Comment: "Put $d=\gcd(x,\,y)$... we conclude $d=\gcd(x,\,y)$" That's where you started. You're supposed to prove $\gcd(d,\,y)=d$, by showing e,g. $\forall f(f|\gcd(d,\,y)\leftrightarrow f|d)$.

Comment: @J.G. It was a typo, edited. Thank you for your correction

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).